# What is the best way to send Usage log to server without waiting for the respond

Tags: android, http

I am sending a usage log such as button click or page navigation to my server via http post, Right now i am using the asynctask doInBackground, but my doInBackground method will not be finish until server respond.

Question is: Is there a better to just send the http post and ignore the response from server. But I need to make sure the server records the log.

```
private static class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "server url";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceOS", "Android"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OSVersion", osVersion));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceManufacturer", manufacturer));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Model", model));
            // and some more
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Error msg will be here = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error msg will be here = e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
Thread r = new Thread(){
public void run(){
  //post request
}

}.start();
```

Comment: I think this is a better approach than mine, but Let say if the server is very slow and take 10 seconds to respond, then the thread will last for 10 seconds.

Comment: @NyanLH .. but you don't have to worry.. Multitasking is good in android... Now you said you just want to send request and leave and does't wait for server to respond.. but reaching server and sending it data and aknowledging it is all part of **sending** .. thread must come to know that its operation was successfull..

Comment: I agree with you, But I am still curious if my idea is technically possible or not. :]

Comment: @NyanLH .. it would't mean anything if it was possible.. if thread is not doing the operation till the end of it, then where will the data go... roam in free space..? it has to reach its destiny and Thread must do that thats how its implemented...

Answer (score 0):

I have put together an asynchronous http operation library for android, please see if it can help you. you can make asyn http calls from a activity or from a IntentService

https://github.com/nareshsvs/android-libraries